# Why my controller is not saving the guarded attributes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a model named Property, it has a lot of attributes mass assignables, and those attributes are working well
But my guarded attributes aren't working, I don't know why

Those attributes are, for example, user_id and status
user_id is supossed to be Auth::user()->id and status must be whatever value I set there
Instead, when I send the form and check my database user_id is 1 and status is always "pending"

My controller function store:
`

```
public function store(PropertyRequest $request) { 
    $newProperty = Property::create($request->validated());    
    $newProperty->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $newProperty->status = 'whatever';

    return redirect()->route('frontend.properties.thanks')->with(['property' => $newProperty]);
}`
```

My model:
`

```
class Property extends Model { use Mediable; use HasSlug; use PropertyMutators; use PropertyScopes;
/**
 * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = ['id', 'user_id', 'status'];

// vincular la propiedad a un usuario
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

// quienes viven en una propiedad
public function residents() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
}
```

PropertyRequest:

```
class PropertyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => ['required', 'max:255'],
            'property_type' => ['required', 'in:casa,duplex,departamento,monoambiente'],
            'city_id' => ['required'],
            'neighborhood_id' => ['sometimes'],
            'address' => ['required'],
            'lat' => ['required', 'regex:/^-?[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,15})?$/'],
            'long' => ['required', 'regex:/^-?[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,15})?$/'],
            'description' => ['required', 'max:1000'],
            'condition' => [
                'required',
                'in:a estrenar,excelente estado,buen estado,aceptable'
            ],
            'living' => ['required_without:men_living,women_living,others_living'],
            'men_living' => ['required_without:living'],
            'women_living' => ['required_without:living'],
            'others_living' => ['required_without:living'],
            'monthly_price_gs' => ['min:0'],
            'monthly_price_usd' => ['min:0'],
            'includes_expenses' => ['sometimes'],
            'expenses' => ['required_with:includes_expenses'],
            'featured_image' => [
                                'required',
                                'file',
                            ],
            'images' => ['sometimes'],
            'furnished' => ['sometimes'],
            'pet_friendly' => ['sometimes'],
            'smokers_allowed' => ['sometimes'],
            'rooms' => ['required', 'min:1', 'max:8'],
            'bathrooms'=> ['required', 'min:1', 'max:8'],
            'garage' => ['required', 'min:0', 'max:8'],
            'area_m2' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_hot_water' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_wifi' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_tv_cable' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_air_conditioning' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_cctv' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_alarm' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_automatic_gate' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_24hs_doorman' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_railings' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_security' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_garden' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_balcony' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_laundry' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_grill' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_lift' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_placard_on_room' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_furnished_kitchen' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_rooftop' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_pool' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_common_room' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_gym' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_deposit' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_playroom' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_spa' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_quincho' => ['sometimes'],
            'has_service_room' => ['sometimes'],
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator($validator) 
    {
        $validator->after(function($validator) {
            if($this->stock == 0 && $this->status == 'available') {
                $validator->errors()->add('stock', 'Status can\'t be available if stock is 0');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is not working about these attributes? and you never saved the model after setting those attributes

Comment: Try adding `$input['status'] = $request->status;` then bellow that add `Property::create($input);`

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving the data after setting the values.

```php
public function store(PropertyRequest $request)
{ 
    $newProperty = Property::create($request->validated());    
    $newProperty->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $newProperty->status = 'whatever';
--> $newProperty->save(); <--

    return redirect()->route('frontend.properties.thanks')->with(['property' => $newProperty]);
}
```